# DropDown UltraCombo programmatically c#

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultracombo

Can anyone help me how to open a ultracombo on runtime ? Example  when a button pressed i want the ultracombo to open.

I'm using infragistics 5.3 and ultracombo not ultracomboEditor.

I have tried

```
combo.ToggleDropdown(),
SendMessage(combo.Handle.ToInt32(), CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, 1, IntPtr.Zero);
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried / Does this compile - `combo.IsOpen = true`?

Comment: combo.isDropDown=true but it's only a read only property

Answer (score 2):

You can use PerformAction on most of the Infragistics WinForm controls to simulate user actions like dropping down the combo.

```
combo.PerformAction(UltraComboAction.Dropdown);
```

Comment: Example: MyComboBox.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraComboAction.Dropdown);

Comment: BTW--don't run this in the constructor of a form--it just ignores it. The form has to be rendered in order for it to work (i.e. "shown" event or later)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [ToggleDropdown](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2014.2/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v14.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo~ToggleDropdown.html) method on the UltraCombo if [IsDroppedDown](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2014.2/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v14.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraDropDownBase~IsDroppedDown.html) is false.